# Can a function be composed of decaying complex sinusoids and is this what the Laplace Transform 'assumes'?

Tags: laplace-transform, intuition

I understand the fact that the Laplace Transform is a 'generalization' of the Fourier Transform and I feel like I've wrapped my head around the Fourier Transform decently enough. I'm trying to translate my understanding to the Laplace Transform, though I'd just like to make sure I'm not walking into a rabbit hole (perhaps I'm already in one).

I understand that via Fourier decomposition, one can turn a function into a summation of complex sinusoids of various frequencies and amplitudes, where the Fourier coefficient of a particular sinusoid can be determined by evaluating the Fourier Transform at the particular sinusoid's frequency. Is there an equivalent 'Laplace' decomposition, where one could convert a function into a sum of complex decaying sinusoids where a particular complex decaying sinusoid's 'Laplace coefficient' can be determined via evaluating the Laplace Transform at that particular value of 's'?

(Apologies for my possible incorrect use of language, I'm new to this)

Comment: Might be useful : [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Fourier_transform ] && [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Laplace_transform ]

Comment: Very informative! That limit relationship, making sigma approach 0, instead of simply letting sigma equal zero was quite cool.

Comment: Formally there is indèed the relatioship between Fourier and Laplace transform which you observed. Computationally it is typically  however  more difficult to invert an L-transform despite the possible detour through the complex domain.

Comment: I think [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2y7n6jw5d0) video gives a great representation of the relation between the two. The Laplace transform along the imaginary axis is the Fourier transform of the function!  
I like to think of the Laplace transform as just the Fourier transform with an extra dimension for exponential growth/decay, demonstrated along the real axis in the video. Just another cool related factor to this question.